# Disable emacs from backingup file in a specified directory

Tags: terminal-emacs, backup

Is it possible to stop emacs from backing up file in a directory?
I have a directory that I use for documenting changes I made to the computer. The files in it are small but I need to make 1 everyday so I imagine its gonna be messy.

Org mode might be a better choice here, but I'm curious if I can disable file backup in this directory instead.
Emacs back up is a good feature for my other files so I don't want to diable it altogether.

Comment: I think this might be helpful. [link here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/how-to-stop-auto-backup-in-some-directory-in-emacs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can backup-directory-alist be set to save in the files directory?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50958/how-can-backup-directory-alist-be-set-to-save-in-the-files-directory)